# mvc music store

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to do the mvc musicstore tutorial, And after part 6 when using the edit I'm getting this error:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Any idea why this is the reason?

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Edit(Album album) 
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified; 
        db.SaveChanges(); 
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    } 
    ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
    ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);

    return View(album);
}
```

it was scaffold

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you're calling `SaveChanges` in-between any Inserts, Updates, or Deletes.

Comment: > ` [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Album album)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
             
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
            ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
            return View(album);`
it was Scaffold

Comment: @dave please update your question with that code, instead of making it a comment on an answer.

Comment: There are savechanges in between. It didn't work. I also have this same problem. Any idea?